# How would you implement complex if statement without parenthesses

Tags: programming-languages

I'm implementing my Java based programming language and I'm struggling with last syntactical problem. I've decided I just don't like those (){}[]. I've just got few crazy ideas, but I'm not sure that I like any of them.

So any idea how to write for example statement for overlapping rectangles without them?

Comment: So, you're looking for different characters or what???

Comment: Have a look at e.g. Python's grammar - completely brace-free and unambiguous. But I don't really get the last sentence?

Comment: You could switch to Visual Basic I suppose... not sure what you're looking for here.

Comment: And would you teach me Gendolkari? :-D Thank you delnan i'll check it out.

Comment: Is it the syntax of the If statement or the programmer wielding it that needs to be fixed? I'd be curious to see an example of what you are trying to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [python's if statement](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/ifStatements.html).  A combination of whitespace and `if [CONDITION]:`

The BASIC language variants typically make use of `IF [CONDITION] THEN [EXECUTE] ENDIF` where the indentation is ignored and optional.